# External Flashdrive Won't Mount on Mac

Tags: mac, mount

I formatted it as a boot drive, and it worked. But now, my Mac reads it as only being 2.4 MB rather than 124 GB, but it recognizes that the drive is 124 GB when trying to partition, although I can't partition, since the drive won't mount in the first place.

Comment: Try a PC - to format it as maybe your flash drive can’t be read by your Mac.

Comment: Do you see multiple partitions in Disk Manager?

Comment: Test it with the Fight Flash Fraud app [F3X](https://github.com/insidegui/F3X) to make sure the size is what is claimed.

Comment: @Alex Disk Utility states that there are two partitions. One of them is 2.39 MB, and the other one is 4.1 KB. When I'm in the partition tab in Disk Utility, under device information , it states that the size of the disk is 123.82 GB.

Comment: @Tetsujin The drive was working fine, but then I used an application to turn it into a boot drive for Linux Mint, and it worked as a boot drive. The drive doesn't work anymore after using it for that purpose.

Comment: What about partition in linux?  Flash drive are not that reliable in my experience.

Comment: @historystamp I fixed the drive through Windows. Thank you. I just needed to use a different operating system, since I have no idea how I would have done it on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I put the flash drive in a computer running Windows 10. I discovered it had an EFI disk partition after seeing the EFI folder through File Explorer, and I realized that that was the thing that was not allowing the drive to work on my Mac. I was unable to delete that partition through Disk Management, since Disk Management won't allow you to modify or delete EFI disk partitions, so I had to use Diskpart. I right clicked the Command Prompt to run it as an administrator. Once it opened, I typed in `diskpart`, and hit enter. I looked over at the Disk Management tab to see which disk it was. I then typed in `select disk 1`, and hit enter. After that, I typed in `list disk`, and hit enter to make sure I selected the right disk, since there's an asterisk to the left of the selected disk. Once I saw I selected the correct disk, I typed in `clear`, and hit enter. It didn't work the first time, so I waited a minute, and typed in `clear` again, and it worked the second time. I then went into Disk Management, and initialized the drive as an exFAT drive, since NTFS doesn't work on Mac without some sort of special program. It now works perfectly fine on my Mac.